# Int-stream in C

Tags: c, arrays, stream, byte, int

I'm implementing a function in C where I convert a byte[] to an int[]. The problem is that the length of the int[] depends on the contents of the byte[] (not just the length of the byte[]) so I won't know the total length of the int[] until I've iterated the entire byte[]. I'm therefore looking for some form av int-stream or dynamically increasing int-list which I can write to and then convert to a int[] once I'm done writing all the ints. My C-experience is a bit limited at the moment so I'm not really sure what's considered best practice to solve this kind of problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: With C you get to express these constructs however you best see fit.  Whether that's an advantage or disadvantage depends on your point of view.

Comment: Do you know the size of `byte[]` before reaching the end?

Comment: @stevehb - no, he doesn't know the size of `int[]` before evaluating the `byte[]`.

Comment: A single pass solution will require realloc, which is more likely to fail as your array grows. Granted, its unlikely unless you are doing some serious processing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this I can think of.

I'm assuming, based on your question, that the transformation of your `char[]` to the corresponding `int[]`s is expensive (which is why you want to avoid performing that calculation twice - once to determine the size, and again to populate the contents.

So, here's how I would go about it:

First, is there a maximum size you can associate to the transformation? EX: Is there a maximum 2-to-1 size difference? (For each char in the char[] can it create "up to X" ints?)

If this is the case, and memory usage isn't an issue (you're not super constrained) - Go ahead and alloc the maximum size, populate it as you perform your translation, and realloc when you're done to shrink your memory footprint.

If this is not the case, you're in tougher waters, and should look to non-contiguous schemes - such as a linked list. Once you've performed your translation and built your linked list, you can then allocate space for your array, and visit each element in the linked list to populate the array.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest method would be to allocate the `int[]` to be the same length (number of elements) as the `byte[]`, and when you're done and know the size, call `realloc` to shrink it.

This assumes, of course, that interpreting the data would never create *more* integers than there are bytes in the stream.

Comment: From the question: "so I won't know the total length of the int[] until I've iterated the entire byte[]."

Comment: @steve: the point is to pick a random size that is guaranteed to be bigger than what you need (so it won't overflow), and then shrink it to the correct size when you're done.

Comment: @Chris - agreed - but that's not what the poster said. He said "to be the same length"

Comment: @Steve: Yes, he doesn't know the total length of the `int[]`. My assumption is that he knows the total length of the `byte[]`, and that if the `byte[]` contains N values, the final `int[]` won't have more than N values. So if he creates an `int[N]`, he's safe and can resize it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

First, inspect byte[] to determine the resulting int[] size.  Then use `malloc()` to allocate the appropriately sized int[] structure.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
    // imagine that the resulting int[] size depends on the sum of the bytes

    int j, size = 0;
    for (j = 0;  byte[j];  ++j)
         size += byte[j];

     int *int_array = (int *) malloc (size);
     for (j = 0;  j < size;  ++j)
          int_array [j] = whatever;
```

Comment: My understanding of his question is that he's specifically looking to avoid this double-analysis you suggest.

Comment: @Steve:  While a single pass might seem cleaner, the description "feels" like a two pass solution is the sure kill.

Comment: You're assuming the conversion from the elements in the byte[] to their corresponding int[] elements is "cheap". Maybe each one involves calculating Pi to a million decimal places... the point is, I don't think the OP would be asking the question the way he is if the conversion was cheap.

Comment: @BrendanLong - I'm only making one assumption - that the transform is expensive enough that he doesn't want to do it twice. And you didn't mention the third option - a non-contiguous storage scheme like a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

First, If you can use C++, then you can just use a `vector`, which is a dynamically-sized array. Otherwise, you'll have to first iterate through your byte array to determine what the int array size should be, then dynamically allocate the int array. Second, C doesn't have a `byte` type, so the type normally used is `char`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char byte_array[ size ];
int i, int_size = 0;
int *int_array;

for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
  int_size += f( byte_array[i] );
}
int_array = (int*) malloc( int_size );
```

where `f()` is some function you write that looks at one element of the byte array to help determine how large the int array should be.

Comment: Like wallyk's solution, this also suffers from the double-analysis problem the OP seems to be trying to avoid.

Comment: @Steve - I see nothing in the question saying that they're trying to avoid double analysis, just that they don't know how to do this at all.